# Controller best practices: Multiple Methods or Multiple cases in Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I'm frequently building controllers where i would like multiple methods
(in addition to index, edit, show, etc.). Most of the time the actions i
desire could be lumped into show as they are simple GET operations,
however I don't want to put too much logic in any one controller action.

Here is a quick example of two different ways to achieve the same
thing...

```
class TwitterFriendController < ApplicationController
  ## lump everything into show?
  def show
    if params[:id] == "follow"
      users = current_user.following
    elsif params[:id] == "follow_me"
      users = current_user.users_who_follow_me
    elsif params[:id] == "following_follow_me"
      users = current_user.following_who_follow_me
    elsif params[:id] == "following_who_do_not_follow_me"
      users = current_user.following_who_do_not_follow_me
    ...
    end
    respond_with do |format|
      format.json do {...}
    end
  end

  ## or split everything out into separate methods, this requires
additional routing
  def following
    ...
  end

  def users_who_follow_me
    ...
  end

  def following_who_follow_me
    ...
  end

  def following_who_do_not_follow_me
    ...
  end
end
```

## Everything in show

- a ton of logic in one method
- DRY ? # lots of extra code needed for logic
- Less routing

## Seperate Methods

- More routing
- not DRY
- Easy method lookup
- Easier to read individual methods

So again the real question is, which one of those techniques are *less*
bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
FOLLOW_WHITELIST = %w[ follow follow_me following_follow_me following_who_follow_me following_who_do_not_follow_me ]

def show
    if FOLLOW_WHITELIST.include? params[:id]
        users = current_user.send params[:id].to_sym
    end
    respond_with do |format|
        format.json do {...}
    end
end
```

This will call whatever method is passed in params[:id], as long as it's in the whitelist (to prevent arbitrary code injection).

If having separate routes was a plus to you (nicer urls?), you could also dynamically generate the methods and routes with something like this:

```
class TwitterFriendController < ApplicationController

    FOLLOW_ACTIONS = %w[ follow follow_me following_follow_me following_who_follow_me following_who_do_not_follow_me ]

    FOLLOW_ACTIONS.each do |action|
        define_method action do
            users = current_user.send action.to_sym
            respond_with do |format|
              format.json do {...}
            end
        end
    end

end
```

And then in routes.rb:

```
FOLLOW_ACTIONS.each do |action|
    match action.to_sym => "controller##{action}"
end
```

Comment: very elegant. However as soon as one of those methods need some additional logic that can't or shouldn't be put in the model, you've just about lost all of your gains. I also wouldn't go so far as to define_method on my controller methods on a production machine, it is keeps all local variable in scope at the time of definition and uses (slightly) more memory. If anyone has any additional thoughts i'm interested to hear before I declare an official "answer"

Comment: I'm not sure what other kind of solution you're waiting for. Once one of those methods needs additional logic, it's no longer against "DRY" principles to have a different method for it.

Comment: I've settled on a presenter pattern and a single show method. There is no "solution" but i figured I would get a few different answers. Thanks for the input, here's some points.